# Skylake Integrated Video says display UNCLAIMED on 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, intel-graphics

I hope anyone can help me, I'm posting this as a new question because all solutions point to installing linux kernel 4.3, but I'm already on 4.4 from the start.

I have tried to install the firmware drivers from the [intel website](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads), the GUC 6.1 and the DMC 1.23 (the contents from dmc 1.26 didn't match the installation instructions).
This all seem to end without errors

Here is some info from the hardware

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

lsmod | grep i915

```
i915_bpo             1261568  0
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        139264  1 i915_bpo
drm                   360448  2 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper
video                  40960  1 i915_bpo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got to solve this after days.
First, I had the problem that the HDMI cable was not recognized.
There recommendations about kernels so upgraded and downgraded several versions but the problem persisted.

I started seeing the drivers as you and installed the Intel Updater Tool. This installed and apparently updated the driver but I had failed to read complete instructions that tell you to add a new source to repository, update and upgrade.

After this, I run the updater tool, but holy, same result: display UNCLAIMED.

Finally I remembered I had altered a line of the GRUB to nomodoset, so I deleted it, rebooted, and voila, the driver was loaded and HDMI recognized.

Sources:

Change boot parameters:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132
Intel updater tool for Ubuntu 16.04: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2
   **Be sure you read all installations instruction down to bottom**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: I'm marking your answer as solved (out of ALL the answers). My problems magically disappeared when i used another OS on another machine =) )